# How to check if the explicit union of two sets is empty?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Below is my code for the explicit union of two lists. How would I get the length of the list rather than the list itself?

```
explicit_union :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
explicit_union as bs = foldl (\as b -> if elem b as then as else as ++ [b]) as bs
```

Comment: Just use the `length` function. Or is this an exercise where you're not allowed to use it?

Comment: also isn't the union empty if and only if both are empty? If you're computing it just to check then there's no point

Comment: @ayrnee: Please don't edit the question to ask something completely different, especially after an answer has already been posted. If you want to ask about intersections as well, please [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

The Union is empty if and only if both sets are empty. So if you're computing the union just for that, you're wasting computational time.

If instead you're given the union or have to use it anyways, length is the most natural method.

However as you only want to know if it's empty, instead of `length ls == 0` you can use `take 1 ls == []`. This way Haskell -- as it's a lazy language --  only has to compute the first element, instead of the whole list as `length` would require

## Edit

As @joseph pointed out, there's a Prelude function to check if a list is null: `null :: [a] -> Bool`

Comment: Or just `null ls`.

Comment: Lol I completely missed that, you can make it your answer or I'll edit mine if you want